# Exchange 2016 Delay Time after Message rate limit is reached

Tags: exchange

I'm trying to find and change the duration of blocks after Message rate limit is reached in the exchange 2016. In the above link I couldn't find anything about how long exchange keeps blocking a connection when Message rate limit is reached

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/mail-flow/message-rate-limits?view=exchserver-2019

Can anyone Help me on this.

Thx

Answer (score 0):

Per my knowledge, there is no such a built-in feature can change the duration of blocks after Message rate limit is reached. You can increase value of the corresponding rate limit or restart the Microsoft Exchange Throttling service to reset the mail flow throttling budgets.

Comment: Actually I want to increase the time limit. For example if 10 emails are sent within a minute the user should be blocked for 1 hour.  Is that possible?